# Standard error of estimate

Tags: standard-error

In order to estimate total weight of rice of 100 bags, a sample of 25 bags was weighted giving the average weight of 50 kg. If the population standard deviation is 1.5 kg, estimate the total weight of 100 bags and find the standard error of the estimate.

Ans: Total weight = $50 \times 100=5000$
and Standard error = $\frac{1.5}{\sqrt(25)}\sqrt(\frac{100-25}{100-1})$

I am not sure about the correctness of my effort. Please help.

Comment: What's the $\sqrt(\frac{100-25}{100-1})$ part about?

Comment: Oh, OK, you're doing a Finite Population Correction (FPC). Is that required in your coursework?

Comment: No No . I just want to know whether my answers are correct or not. If not, then I will try again. I am new in the field of sampling and statistics